# OOP c# Why do I get a protection level error when my item is public

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Elev x;
    ArrayList listaStudenti;
    ListViewItem itm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listaStudenti = new ArrayList();
        x=new Elev();         

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Elev
{
    public String nume;
    public int varsta;

    Elev(string _nume, int _varsta)
    {
        this.nume = _nume;
        this.varsta = _varsta;

    }
}
```

Error   1   'pregatiret.Elev.Elev(string, int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level c:\users\marius\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\pregatiret\pregatiret\Form1.cs    26

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public class is inaccessible due to its protection level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404264/public-class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor is `private` you should make it `public`

```
public Elev(string _nume, int _varsta)
{
    this.nume = _nume;
    this.varsta = _varsta;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Elev`'s constructor doesn't have any access specifier. It is treated as `private`. Specify `public` access specifier.

```
public Elev(string _nume, int _varsta)
{
}
```

See: [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level
>   for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, is **private by default**.

You should consider using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` if you are targeting .Net framework 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not `public`, it's private:

```
Elev(string _nume, int _varsta)
{
    this.nume = _nume;
    this.varsta = _varsta;

}
```

The default access modifier in C# is private.  You wanted:

```
public Elev(string _nume, int _varsta)
{
    this.nume = _nume;
    this.varsta = _varsta;

}
```

---

As an aside, there is no good reason to use `ArrayList` anymore unless you absolutely have to in order to interact with some old API.

Answer (score 0):

Elev() needs to be public as well

this is a private constructor so it cannot be accessed

```
public Elev()...
```