# S3 and .net Amazon SDK - GetObject is inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core

I am trying to download a file from S3 to a byte array iin .net using c#.

I am following the below method:

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWEST2);
    using (client)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
        getObjectRequest.BucketName = Bucketname;
        getObjectRequest.Key = Keyname;

        using (var getObjectResponse = client.GetObject(getObjectRequest))
        {
            getObjectResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(ms);
        }
 }
```

I referred to a stackoverflow answer and followed the above method.

However I am getting the following error saying;

**GetObject is inaccessible  due to protection level.**

I am just learning S3, I am now confused if this error is because of bucket policy or class scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Public class is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404264/public-class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level)

Comment: @vahdet - not a duplicate of the question you linked

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You mention .NET Core: most of the AWS APIs for .Net Core and .NET Standard only provide Async variants.  You should use `GetObjectAsync`.

It's surprising that Amazon introduced this incompatibility as it would have been easy to provide a synchronous version, using code something like:

```
var task = s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
task.Wait();
return task.Result;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Would have taken hours to figure this out:)

Comment: @Joe just out of curiosity. do we really need that task.Wait()?  Is this any different than using .Result at the end of s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request); ? isn't it going to run it syncronously anyways?

Comment: @curiousBoy - no we don't.  In fact, it might be better to call `GetAwaiter().GetResult` which has the advantage that it will propagate the original exception rather than wrapping it in an AggregateException, thus being "more compatible" with the synchronous GetObject method