# Error CS0122: 'GameManager.Instance' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I get this error:

> Error CS0122: 'GameManager.Instance' is inaccessible due to its protection level

If anybody knows how to solve this error, please tell me.

I am showing my code as a screenshot below:

image link :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKy2u.jpg

GameManager code link:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUxHS.jpg

Comment: Show the game manager class. It's this and instance field/property public?

Comment: Sir I can't understand what you want to show

Comment: I see `Instance` property is already public so you shouldn't see this error. Check if you are nto refering to a wrong class definition (in another project, no recompiled, not saved etc)? can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Sir I solve my error but it takes lot's of time

Answer (score 1):

This is because access to the variable is limited, Make sure every variable you call from another class is `public`.

```
public static GameManager Instance;
```

for more info: ([Public class is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404264/public-class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level))

Comment: The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404264/public-class-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level) you provided said the constructor is not accessible, OPs' Instance property is already Public. Mind explaining a littler more?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614818/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-protected-and-having-no#:~:text=public%20%2D%20can%20be%20access%20by,inherits%20off%20of%20the%20class.)

Comment: This my game manager code:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUxHS.jpg        what should I change